# Instantiating an enum

Tags: java, enums

The below code throws a lot of errors at me. So
why is it not possible to have an enum like below with only the constructor so that it can be instantiated else where??

```
public  class TestEnum{
     enum Animal
     {
         public Animal(String name)
         {
             this.name = name;
         }
         String name;
     }
}
```

Is there any way of instatiating enum or does it violate the very basic property/functionality of enums and it should only be used for creating a set of,say, ready-made objects??

Comment: Enums can not be instantiated, By the way, what is the differences of your intended object and a normal class if it has to be instantiated?

Comment: Yeah, this isn't what enums are for at all.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh: ya i get it. I thought of a model wherein i get to have ready-made/fixed set of objects and also should have an option for instantiating when needed. I guess that is not possible using enums, right!

Answer (score 9):

Because an [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) consists of enumerated constant values (that is constant at compile and run-time)

Your code is otherwise (almost) correct, for example

```
enum Animal {
  Dog("Bark"), Cat("Meow"); // Dog and Cat.
  Animal(String name) {     // No, it can't be public.
    this.name = name;
  }

  String name;
}
```

If you want dynamic values, use a `class`.

Comment: ya i get t. I thought of a model wherein i get to have ready-made/fixed set of objects and also should have an option for instantiating when needed. I guess that is not possible using enums, right!

Comment: @aarish I think you are looking for a Factory of Animals(sounds funny) or a Map with these animals. Watch out for thread safety.

Comment: @aarish Program to an *interface*. Your class and your enum can both implement that interface. Then you could return the enum when appropriate, or create an instance of your class.